# c# - Спрятать MenuStrip когда курсор не находится на нем

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse-event

Мне необходимо показывать MenuStrip только когда на него наведен курсор, а когда курсор покидает MenuStrip - прятать. Как я понял, сделать это с можно помощью значения Visible:

```
public void MainMenuStrip_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainMenuStrip.Visible = true;
}

public void MainMenuStrip_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainMenuStrip.Visible = false;
}
```

Но этот код не работает. Как правильно обрабатывать перемещения курсора относительно меню?

Comment: Как вы собираетесь наводить курсор на какой то контрол, если он спрятан?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно проверять нахождение курсора по координатам и отображать элемент, данный код разместить в событии MouseMove у формы

```
if (e.Y <= menuStrip1.Height && !menuStrip1.Visible)
    menuStrip1.Visible = true;
if (e.Y> menuStrip1.Height && menuStrip1.Visible)
    menuStrip1.Visible = false;
```

Comment: а если форму растянуть?

Comment: @TEA я предположил, что у человека задавшего вопрос, MenuStrip имеет свойство Dock = DockStyle.Top, а так в любом случае можно рассчитать размеры контрола по формуле, это всего лишь один из вариантов решения поставленной задачи

Comment: @Hazatdum Благодарю! Этим методом я и воспользовался.

Answer (score 0):

Добавить control в панель и проверять мышку на нахождение в этой панели(панель не прятать)